# Second add to cart button on product page does not add related products - Magento 2.4.2

Tags: product, addtocart, related-products

We have a second add to cart button on our product page, using the following code, see below.

But when a related product is checked and this second add to cart button is clicked, the related product is not added to the cart. When we use the default add to cart button on the product page, the related product is added successfully to the cart.

I guess it has something to do with the duplicate of the `data-role="tocart-form"`, but I can not find the related code and solution.

Any idea how we can solve this issue?

```
        <div class="box-tocart">
        <form data-role="tocart-form" id="product_addtocart_form_sticky" class="product_addtocart_form_sticky" action="<?php echo $block->getAddToCartUrl($product); ?>" method="post">
        <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
            <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart primary small-button">
                <span><i class="fad fa-shopping-cart"></i><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
            </button>  
        </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check the core-code for `id="product_addtocart_form"`.

Most likely, there's a submit function, and you have to apply it to `id="product_addtocart_form_sticky"` as well.

**EDIT**

If you look into `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml`, you see that there's a hidden input field `<input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />`

I'd search the codebase where this field is populated, and go on from there.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea where to add this part to the submit function?

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: Thanks! Seems that we indeed missed the `<input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />` in the second form. Added this part and now it works perfect.

Comment: hi @JGeer... you mention second form, can i ask which second form?